# Google App Script: how to display google drive files with links to templated HTML

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm new in both Google App Scripting and JavaScript. So, I'm trying to display the grabbed files from my Google Drive with links however when running `displayData();` it's literally showing the link and the title of the file on the page without the actual link in it. Here's picture of the html
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRZlL.png).

Here's what I have so far:

**Code.gs**

```
function doGet() {
  var output = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Page').evaluate();
  return output;
}

function include(filename){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
  .getContent();
}

function displayData() {
  var dir = 'Somefoldername';
  var foldername = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dir).next();
  var foldercont = foldername.getFiles();
  var listicon = '<img src="https://drive-thirdparty.googleusercontent.com/16/type/application/vnd.google-apps.document">';
  var file, title, links, list = []; 
  while (contents.hasNext()) {
    file = foldercont.next();
    title = file.getName();
    links = file.getUrl();
    date = file.getDateCreated();
    
    list.push('<tr><td>' + listicon + '<a href ="' + links + '">' + title +'</td></tr>');
  }
  return list;
```

**Page.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('Stylesheet'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="doclist">
    <?= displayData(); ?>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How would I display the Google Drive file hyperlinks in the html template?

Thank you.

Comment: contents is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Here is a Sample Code:

> **Note:**
>
> - I temporarily removed `<?!= include('Stylesheet'); ?>` in the html file since it is not defined.

**Code.gs**

```
function doGet() {
  var output = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Page').evaluate();
  return output;
}

function include(filename){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
  .getContent();
}

function displayData() {
  var dir = 'Somefoldername';
  var foldername = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dir).next();
  var foldercont = foldername.getFiles();
  var listicon = '<img src="https://drive-thirdparty.googleusercontent.com/16/type/application/vnd.google-apps.document">';
  var file, title, links, list = []; 
  while (foldercont.hasNext()) {
    file = foldercont.next();
    title = file.getName();
    links = file.getUrl();
    date = file.getDateCreated();
    
    list.push('<tr><td>' + listicon + '<a href ="' + links + '">' + title +'</td></tr>');
  }
  return list.join(' ');
}
```

**Modifications done:**

- Replace `while (contents.hasNext())` with `while (foldercont.hasNext())`
- Combine your array `list` into a single string using [array.join(' ')](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) with `spaces` as its `separator`

**Page.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(tblStr){
      document.getElementById('FileList').innerHTML = tblStr;
    }).displayData();
    </script>
    <table id="FileList">
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Modifications done:**

- I added a table in the html body with the id "FileList"
- I called the server-side function `displayData()` using [google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function).displayData()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function)). The return value of `displayData()` will be passed to the callback function's first parameter.
- I updated the table's content based on the `displayData()`'s return value using this procedure `document.getElementById('FileList').innerHTML = tblStr;`

### Output:

[image]

Comment: I tried adding 'list.join()' at the end but doesn't seem to display still. Guess I'm suppose to call the server-side function and that's the one missing in the html template. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Some observations:

1. The function is returning an array `list = []`, and you are pushing data into that array.
2. Your HTML in the screenshot has stray commas in it between each item: `...</td></tr>,<tr><td>...`.
3. You shouldn't place a `<div>` inside a table.

Both of these suggest that you should be appending your data to a string variable, instead of pushing data into an array.

Then return that string from your function, instead of the array.

The string variable will contain the entire contents of your HTML rows and columns.

For the `<div>`, remove it and place the class in the body:

```
<body class="doclist">
```

Depending on how your CSS is set up, that may need modifying to accommodate this change.

Final suggestion: take the resulting HTML which is generated and run it through a validator - for example: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

That may find some additional issues which need correcting.